# undefined index pic in codeigniter image upload

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

Hey guyx i'm trying to upload an image in codeingniter but it keeps giving me an error like this

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: pic

Filename: controllers/dou.php

Line Number: 7
```

My Upload view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo form_open('dou/upload');?>

<?php echo form_upload('pic'); ?>
    <?php echo form_submit('submit','Save');?>
<?php echo form_close();?>
</body>
</html>
```

And my controller

```
<?php 
    class DoU extends XM_Controller {
        public function index(){
            $this->load->view('upload_view1',array('error' => ''));
        }
        public function upload(){
            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tem_nam'])) {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tem_nam'], './assets'.$_FILES['pic']['name']);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated ..

i have tried printing the array "$_FILES" but it was totally empty 
what am i doing wrong ??

Comment: use form_open_multipart() instead of form_open()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
form_open_multipart()
```

function, because you have *file upload*.

From documents: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html (actual in CI3, too)